# How do I programmatically set property of control in aspx file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, expression

This may be a very dumb question but I can't seem to get it working. I use at many places the following syntax for dynamically binding a property of a control in aspx file to the resource entry, e.g.

```
<SomeFunnyControl Text="<%$ Resources : ResClass, ResEntry %>" />
```

I want to do a similar thing with a class containing some constants, something like

```
<SomeFunnyControl Text="<%= MyConstantsClass.MyStringConstant %>" />
```

But this doesn't seem to work, it simply sets the text to the **exact** expression without evaluating it. I am using ASP.NET 3.5 btw.

I have tried the databinding approach but I get an HttpParseException saying

> Databinding expressions are only
>   supported on objects that have a
>   DataBinding event.

Comment: Silly question in return: is *MyConstantsClass* static?

Comment: No, does it make a difference ? MyStringConstant is public const string

Comment: hmm..a public const string within which class?? What is MyConstantsClass exactly? Is it a public/protected property on your page where the Label resides??

Comment: If you think the property called might be a problem try Text='<%# "test" %>'

Comment: No, it's a completely separate class where the MyStringConstant is public const string field (not a property). I didn't think it matters as long as it's server-side executable expression that returns string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article: [The CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx) might be interesting/helpful (although written for ASP.NET 2.0).

It (seems) to enable you to write `... Text="<%$ Code: DateTime.Now %>" ...`. That might help, no? It is quite a bit of overhead, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMyStringConstant" runat="server" Text='<%# MyConstantsClass.MyStringConstant %&>'></asp:Label>
```

You also need to call DataBinding on that control, like this:

```
lblMyStringConstant.DataBind();
```

(It is not necessary if you are calling DataBind on entire Page or parent container of this label, because it will call DataBind for all its children)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" Text="<%# SomeText %>" runat="server" />
```

Then call lbl.DataBind(); or databind some container of the label.

Comment: Ok, I have to admit I simplified it a little bit, I'm not doing it for labels but for some properties nested in controls I can't really influence so much. Is there no easier way ?

Comment: When you databind those controls it should work in a similar fashion

Comment: Maybe post a more exact example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have it like this it should work actually:

```
public static class MyConstantsClass
{
   public static string MyStringConstant = "Hello World!";
}
```

or alternatively

```
public class MyConstantsClass
{
   public const string MyStringConstant = "Hello World!";
}
```

If you declare it like

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%= MyNamespace.MyConstantsClass.MyStringConstant %>"></asp:Label>
```

it won't work and the output will be "`<%= MyNamespace.MyConstantsClass.MyStringConstant %>`".

What you could do alternatively is to write it like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"><%= MyNamespace.MyConstantsClass.MyStringConstant %></asp:Label>
```

This works perfectly for me, but note you have to provide the fully qualified namespace to your class in the ASPX definition. At least otherwise it didn't work for me.